# Would be ok to ask a question that can have many different answers depending where the person is from?

Tags: discusión

Since I saw this question [nuevos zapatos por/para España?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3571/nuevos-zapatos-por-para-espana/3573#3573)

I have been thinking that it would be cool to know how people says "sport shoes" in different Spanish speaking countries. Because it seems there is a huge variety on this topic.
Actually I have been in more than one Spanish speaking country, and I wouldn't be able to tell an universal way to say sports shoes, beyond "calzado deportivo", which is rather formal and generic.

So would it be OK to ask something like "How do you say "sport shoes" in different Spanish speaking countries?" 
I would like to come up with the most generic way possible of saying the word.
But since this is a Q&A site I don't know if this kind of question would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest focusing your question to the specific region you care about.  Questions on SE should generally be relevant to you, to a specific problem you are facing.  So with that in mind, which region(s) do you care about?  If you are living in Mexico, it would be appropriate to ask how to say "sport shoes" in Mexico--perhaps even for the specific region where you will be living (as Mexico is rather large).  Will you be vacationing in Peru? Ask about there.

But I would shy away from asking "What are all of the regional ways to say X?"  That's a list question, and thus "not constructive".

Another approach would be "I know that in Mexico the word for X is Y. How widely used/understood is this term Y in other Spanish-speaking countries?"

Another option would be to ask for a term that is recognized in all (or the majority) of Spanish-speaking regions, if that's what you're seeking.

Comment: Well but this is not about the region itself, but the Language, like what is the most generally accepted word for sport shoes. A word everyone would understand, I am not sure if it exists at all :S

Comment: @Dzyann: That seems like an acceptable question to me.

Comment: @Dzyann: I agree with Flimzy, ask the question and see what happens! :O)

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, but I am not sure it totally fits my question. Should I edit my question to include my comment from above? Or would you edit yours?